# Show the user's username in post view w/ related comment

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, containable

I am a newbie in CakePHP 1.3... I want to display or show the USER's username instead of USER's id, who post the COMMENTS in the POST view... Anyone can help me please?

Here is the model association I made:

1. POSTS 'has many' COMMENTS
2. COMMENTS 'belongs to' USERS

POST->COMMENT->USER

I already read the Containable Behavior of CakePHP 1.3, but still I can't understand it well... Please help me what codes to put in the post_controller's view & view.ctp that can show the related's related table in the POST view.

And How to call the USER's data in the POST view.

I'm still confused.

Thanks in Advance, Azure

Comment: Help me to solve this please! :{

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumptions**

You have three tables as below

```
(1) Posts
    *  id
    *  title

(2) Comments
    * id
    * post_id
    * user_id

(3) Users
    * id
    * name
```

View Function in **PostsController.php** file

```
public function view($id) {
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    $this->Post->recursive=2;
    $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
    if (!$post) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }
    $this->set('post', $post);
}
```

Content of **view.ctp** file in app/View/Posts/ folder

```
<!-- File: /app/View/Posts/view.ctp -->
<h1><?php echo 'Post ID : '.h($post['Post']['id']); ?></h1>
<h1><?php echo 'Post Title : '.h($post['Post']['title']); ?></h1>
<?php 
echo 'Comments By Users : ';
if(!empty($post['Comment'])){
    foreach ($post['Comment'] as $key=>$value){?>
    <p>User Name : <?php echo $value['User']['name'];?></p>
    <?php }
}
else {
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'No Comments Yet';
} ?>
```

**Model File : User.php**

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Comment' => array(
                'className' => 'Comment',
        )
);
}
?>
```

**Model File : Comment.php**

```
<?php
class Comment extends AppModel {
public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
                'className' => 'User',
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
);
}
?>
```

**Model File : Post.php**

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel {
public $hasMany = array(
        'Comment' => array(
                'className' => 'Comment',
        )
);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kevin!
This codes help me so much. :D

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are saving user id in comments table and user names are in users table who posts the comment, then use the below solution

In Controller method:

```
$userdata=$this->User->find('all',array('fields'=>array('id','username'),'recursive'=>-1));
$userid=Set::extract('/User/id', $userdata);
$username=Set::extract('/User/username', $userdata);
$data=array_combine($username,$userid);
$this->set('name',$data);
```

In View:

```
$cid=$var['Comment']['user_id'];
$username=array_search($cid, $name);
echo $username;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to try to solve my problem Arsh... I Appreciate that. :D